# Create or edit an article using a form in the frontend in joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, form, content, front-end

I need edit to create articles in Joomla from the frontend using a form because my articles follow a pattern.

What I want when creating or editing articles it is to introduce only: a title, upload 2 files, select the category of the article and a text field.

Are there any existing extensions that allows to create and edit items from the frontend part through a pre-designed form?

Besides this I would like the items are all show as a database table and click on them to access desired or can be selected for editing article.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider SEBLOD or Form2Content for this task depending on the overall complexity of your project.

Choose form2content if you want to get up and running quick (uses smarty php for templating ), and choose SEBLOD if you don't like limitations and have some code skills ( php ).

Comment: Thanks for the information, I tried the lite version of form2content but you can not configure the form of frontend...
I'll try SEBLOD thanks, I need more help because  I don't know programing because I need a free extension to cover these functionalities.
Thanks

Comment: SEBLOD has a learning curve, but if you make webpages every now and then, its worth it.

Comment: Do you know why my button save in form not found?? If you know how works SEBLOD, can you help me please? Is so urgent and important for me. Thanks

Comment: You have to add all fields to all views ( content, admin form, frontend form, list ect ) + make sure you output all fields in your template part.